# Filtering observable collection

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Im trying to filter a observable collection with a query like this

```
var IEquip = from eq in this.reportDocument.Document.InspectionData.Equipments where eq.PartData.ReportIncluded = true
                             orderby eq.PartData.Order ascending
                             select eq;
```

This seems to work , but when i try to iterate trough IEquip

```
foreach (EquipmentItem eq in IEquip)
{
....
}
```

all the ReportIncluded are set to true and i can see the setter on ReportIncluded being called. I have emptied the logic inside the loop with same results. All the ReportInclude are set on first iteration in the loop. What am i missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using assignment operator instead of equality:

```
eq.PartData.ReportIncluded = true
// instead of
eq.PartData.ReportIncluded == true
```

Comment: Thx, been writing to much VB6 in my days

Answer (score 3):

Don't confuse `=` and `==`. Actually there's no need to compare a boolean to the `true` and `false` literals (unless it's a *nullable* boolean). So maybe you can just write `where eq.PartData.ReportIncluded` without any `== true`?

Comment: Same problem is sometimes seen in other situations, like if people say `if (someVar = false) { ... }`, they actually assign to `someVar`. If `someVar` is a pure boolean, they should use `if (!someVar)` instead. But if `someVar` is a nullable boolean (a `bool?`), they could say `if (someVar == false)`. The **right-hand side** of the comparison will be automatically "lifted" to `(bool?)false`. The good news is that the return type of `someVar = (bool?)false` differs from that of `someVar == (bool?)false`, so it won't compile if you accidentally use a `=` instead of `==` with nullables.